# XML::LibXSLT fails to install at Heroku

Tags: perl, heroku, libxslt

I fail to install [XML::LibXSLT](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXSLT) on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). It looks like the required libraries `gdbm` is not installed, despite being [listed as installed Ubuntu packages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-ubuntu-packages) at Heroku stack cedar and cedar-14. Similar problems have been reported [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635034/cpan-xmllibxslt-failed-to-install) but not on Heroku and its not allowed to install new Ubuntu packages.

To reproduce the error, create a minimal repository, requiring XML::LibXSLT in `cpanfile`:

```
$ git init
$ echo 'requires "XML::LibXSLT";' > cpanfile
$ echo 'sub { [200,[], ['Hello World']] }' > app.psgi
$ git add cpanfile app.psgi
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Create a new Heroku app with heroku-buildpack-perl to run `cpanm`:

```
$ heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/miyagawa/heroku-buildpack-perl.git
$ git push heroku master
```

The error log contains

```
! Installing XML::LibXSLT failed. See /app/.cpanm/work/1412752363.1663/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'XML::LibXSLT' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for ..
```

To get more verbose error message, try to install by hand:

```
$ heroku run cpanm --verbose XML::LibXSLT
```

The fails with the following error

```
....
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib" cc  -shared -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector LibXSLT.o perl-libxml-mm.o  -o blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.so   \
   -L/usr/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -lexslt -lgdbm -lgdbm_compat -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt  \

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdbm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.so] Error 1
FAIL
! Installing XML::LibXSLT failed. See /app/.cpanm/work/1412753360.2/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

As [noted above](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-ubuntu-packages), Heroku has installed Ubuntu packages `libgdbm3` and `libxslt1-dev` (confirm with `heroku run dpkg --get-selection`) so I wonder why compilation still fails.

Comment: You would need the `libgdbm-dev` package. The `*-dev` packages include the header files, which are required for linking. As you can't install packages, you might be able to install XML::LibXSLT with the header files located in a directory under your control. This is then a question of feeding the appropriate paths to the compiler.

Comment: thanks. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux) will help to adjust the compiler settings.

Comment: I just asked Heroku to add libgdbm-dev to their stack.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to install the developer package of libgdbm

```
apt-get install libgdbm-dev
```

CPAN needs often the dev-packages to install the modules.